# How is access token refreshed / acquired when using API Client Library for .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have one quick question related to "acquiring a new access token upon expiration". I have read some tutorials where people write code to manually request a new access token.

In my case I wrote an ASP.NET MVC app to access Google APIs, such as Gmail API, and I am using API Client Library for .NET for that.

After OAuth 2.0 authorization I get back the **result** object of type **AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult**.

Where **result.Credential.Token** contains **AccessToken** and **RefreshToken** properties.

I save the refresh token in my web.config the very first time when it comes back (after the consent screen). All next requests dont have a refresh token, only an access token that expires after 1 hour.

So, my question is - before I make a call to instantiate a Gmail Service, I assign previously saved refresh token:

```
result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshToken"];
var service = new GmailService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential });
```

When **result.Credential.Token.AccessToken** expires, does Gmail API (or any other API Client Library for .NET) acquires a new access token automatically if **result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken** was assigned a valid refresh token value previously saved, like in my code sample?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE - More clarification to my question** With the same refresh token, how many times I can aquire a new access token when making calls to Google API?
I will explain: access token expires in 1 hour, right.
If I keep making calls with, lets say, 10 minutes intervals to Gmail API (for example), after 6 calls (1 hour limit), Gmail API will use my refresh token to acquire a new access token. After 6 more calls (1 more hour) the whole thing repeats itself. Question - is there a limit to it? Remember, I am not changing my refresh token. Same refresh token is being used to acquire a new access token. And for how long this repetitive calls may continue without any error?

---

**UPDATE AFTER THE TEST**
I let my application run on my local machine in Visual Studio DEBUG mode trying to catch any exception, NO Human interaction.
The application kept receiving AJAX calls to Gmail Action with 2 minutes interval, everything was working fine, I went to the gym, came back 2 hours later - oops, Visual Studio debug is open on this **Token has been revoked exception**, here we go, so it's clear the token was revoked by the Google API service, as you can see from the Debug window. The only question remains - why, since there are no specific details are provided, there is no Inner Exception just that general error message and no reason, but the source is clear - Google API, we can even see it came back from

> Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() в
>   C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:row
>   96

I am guessing the service shuts down (revokes a token) after N number of calls, maybe within certain interval. If some one knows the limitations of Google API in terms of number of calls or time intervals between calls, please let me know.

[image]

It seems that Matthew Riley, the custodian of Google API on github, coded some logic to revoke a token based on some criteria: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: assuming you are doing it right the first time you make a call against the API the client library will get a new access token for you and it will refresh it for you when needed.

Comment: @DaImTo: Sounds like a good deal :) One question though: can this be done indefinitely long, unlimited number of times, or I will get an error at some point?

Answer (score 2):

Long response to comment :

> One question though: can this be done indefinitely long, unlimited number of times, or I will get an error at some point?

Refresh tokens can be come invalid for the following reasons:

1. user can revoke it in there google account.
2. if a refresh token isn't used for 6 months to get a new access token it will expire automatically.
3. If a user authenticates your application you get a refresh token if they do it again you get a different refresh token.  Both will work.  you can do this up to 26 times. on the 27 th time the user Authenticates your application the first one you got will expire.  You can only have 26 live refresh tokens.  (DONT ASK how I know this! "#¤%&)

So assuming you don't reauthentcate your application to many times, use the refresh token at least once every six months.  You can use it as many times as you want.

**Update for comment:**

I think you are still confused.  Access tokens expire after 1 hour.  Refresh tokens only expire for the above reasons you can use them as many times as you like. To get a new access token.

However you can only have 25 working refresh tokens.

Lets say I have a windows service application that backs up files to a users Google drive account.  A user installs it on a server and authenticates it and gets a refresh token.  Every night the windows service runs and backs up the files to google drive, it uses the refresh token to get a new access token.

Lets say this user really likes my auto super imba backup service.  He installs it on another server.  He gets another refresh token and the application goes about its business uploading files at night

Lets say my super user really has a server farm he installs my application on 25 servers.  Those applications will be able to get new access tokens forever.

However if this crazy user installs it the 26 th time on a different server getting a new refresh token for this server.   The first server they installed it on will stop working because google only allows you to have 25 outstanding refresh tokens for an application.

This is user application based so you can have any number of users each with a max of 25 refresh tokens

Comment: Thanks, actually 25 refresh tokens, it says right here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration
However it doesn't say during what time period this limit of 25 applies to

Comment: My testing says 26 but if they have it documented now I wont argue.

Comment: It doesn't matter :) However it doesn't say during what time period this limit of 25 applies to. What, 25 for lifetime, for a week? But my question is more like this: how many times I can use the same refresh token? Please take a look at my question, I will rephrase it in bold.

Comment: Refresh tokens are Client id / user based.  A user can only have 25 valid refresh tokens to your application (client id) before the old ones start to expire.    You can use a refresh token as many times as you want to get a new access token until the end of time or it expires.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe I missed something, but as far as I understand, access token expires, not a refresh token, that's why we save refresh token, to acquire a new **access token**, because previous access token (not a refresh token) has expired. expiration applies to access token. Refresh tokens have only limit of 25/26, but no expiration time.

Comment: Know what, I am going to run an experiment, I will keep my app running in Debug mode with 2 min interval calls to Gmail API and try to see if I get any exception and its details... Started the app at 10:00 AM EST

Comment: try wall of text  :)

Comment: This is interesting, I have updated my post with Tests Results, take a look.

Comment: DaImTo, I have read you comment update, I am not confused (I hope :), I am totally agree with what you are saying, but the problem I was experiencing is a different one, it is true theoretically:) that I can use same refresh token (forget about 25 limit for a sec, its irrelevant to my question) to call Google API indefinitely, constantly reacquiring new access tokens again and again. And it does, it does... until certain moment, then I start receiving "Token revoked" error from Google API. Please see my post updated with debug info, you'll see what I am talking about.